# Binding default text in a textbox in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to create a databound textbox that must show a default string value fetched from a relation in the database at the back end. This is an ASP.NET Web forms applications. also want the user to be able to write to that textbox and change the default during which I want be written`enter code here` back to the database. I am using code behind class and here are relevant the contents of my .aspx page:

I initialize the variables inside the Page_load method and as an intermediate implementation, I am hardcoding some dates. Once I get this working, I will use LINQ to weite a simple query and populate these class attributes accordingly:

I am using code behind class and here are relevant the contents of my .aspx page:

```
<div class="content" style="text-align: center">
    <p>The following are the default start and end dates. Change if inappropriate</p>
    <p> <asp:TextBox ID="StartDate" runat="server" Text=Bind("Dates.startDate") Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox> </p>    
    <p> <asp:TextBox ID="EndDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Dates.endDate")%>' Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox> </p>    
</div>
```

Here are the contents of the code behind class .aspx.vb:
Public Class Dates

```
    Public Property startDate() As String
        Get
            Return m_startDate
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_startDate = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_startDate As String

    Public Property endDate() As String
        Get
            Return m_endDate
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_endDate = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_endDate As String
End Class
```

I initialize the variables inside the Page_load method and as an intermediate implementation, I am hardcoding some dates. Once I get this working, I will use LINQ to weite a simple query and populate these class attributes accordingly:

```
Dim Dates As New Dates()
Dates.startDate = "2019-01-01"
Dates.endDate = "2019-01-02"
```

My question: 
The final output is not showing the dates, what am I doing wrong here? It's just showing an empty textbox. Further it is not allowing me to edit it.

Comment: use like this,
<asp:TextBox ID="EndDate" runat="server" Text='<%# string.format("{0}",Dates.endDate)"%>' Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>

Answer (score 0):

Try using Jquery to create a textbox with DatePicker

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#txtsdate").datepicker({
                defaultDate: "+1w",
                changeMonth: true,
                onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                    $("#txtedate").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
                }
            });

        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            Start Date:<asp:TextBox ID="txtsdate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```